# Flutter: Having a spinning sync button in the appbar

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to animate an IconButton in the AppBar, so to spin while updating a document in the database

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  DatabaseService().signInAutomatically();
                },
                tooltip: 'Refresh connection status',
                icon: const Icon(Icons.sync),
                color: Colors.white,
              )
            ],
            title: Constants.appname,
            flexibleSpace: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                  Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                  Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary
                ], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
              ),
            ),
            toolbarHeight: 110,
            centerTitle: true,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            bottom: const TabBar(
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.work, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home_work, color: Colors.white),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const StampInFromOffice(),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const StampInFromHome(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've been trying to implement the answer given in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62373736/flutter-spinning-sync-icon-in-appbar) posed on Stackoverflow, but to make that solution work I would need to make the HomeScreen Widget stateful, and I'd prefer to keep the HomeScreen widget a stateless widget. How do I make the icon button animated while keeping the HomeScreen a stateless widget.

Comment: "I want to animate an IconButton" so use `AnimatedBuilfer` / `ListenableBuilder` / `ValueListenableBuilder`

Comment: You can't make an animation in StatelessWidget becuause never changes states. If you are looking for an alternative, see [flutter hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks). With flutter_hooks, you can use hooks like useEffect to execute code in response to specific changes, such as the creation or destruction of the widget, or when a state variable changes. This provides control over the widget's lifecycle and may help avoid the need for StatefulWidget in your case.